# Request to reopen: 'import module' vs. 'from module import function'

Tags: discussion, status-completed, vote-to-reopen

I stumbled upon this question today: ['import module' vs. 'from module import function'](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/import-module-vs-from-module-import-function)

It was closed as not constructive, but honestly I believed it's a very good fit for the site.  As you can see from the top answer:

1. The question admits answers backed by facts
2. There are available references supporting those facts
3. Even though there could be religious/off-topic/not constructive arguments made, the fact is that this question had at least one objective, fact-based answer.

I'd be happy to see this question reopened, even though it was already answered, because I think it's indeed a good fit for programmers.SE.

Honestly, it pains me to see so many closed questions on the front page sometimes.  Now I agree most of them shouldn't be on here, but it must be discouraging for new users as well as confusing.  It's hard to tell what's a good question on programmers.SE, much more so than on SO, so I think good questions like this one should stay open.

Comment: Thanks a lot @pwny!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question attracted a sub par answer, and I'm guessing that was the main reason for the close votes (the "foo" vs "bar" title doesn't look good either). Crappy one-liners are almost always a very strong hint that the question is not constructive, but in this case I think it was just coincidental.

I've removed the non answer and re-opened it, hopefully the two existing good answers will detract further crappy one-liners.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I agree that answer was terrible and the remaining ones are really nice.